# Necesito hacer una consulta que muestre el pasajero que haya viajado en todos los aviones de la compañia

Tags: sql

Sean los siguientes esquemas de relación:

```
•   Tramo (Nro-vuelo, Desde, Hasta)

•   Avión_Utilizado (nro-vuelo, tipo-avión, nroavión)

•   Info_pasajeros (nro - vuelo, documento-identidad, nombre, fecha)
```

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
SELECT Info_Pasajeros.Nombre
FROM Tramo
INNER JOIN Info_Pasajeros ON Info_Pasajeros.NroVuelo = Tramo.NroVuelo
INNER JOIN Avion_Utilizado ON Avion_Utilizado.NroVuelo = Tramo.NroVuelo
GROUP BY Info_Pasajeros.Nombre
HAVING count(Info_Pasajeros.CodPasajero) = count(Avion_Utilizado.CodAvion)
```

Comment: El diseño no está correcto. Por ejemplo la tabla `Avión_Utilizado` no debería tener la columna `nro-vuelo`, sino que la tabla `Tramo` debería tener la columna `nroavion`

Comment: ¿A qué se debe un -3 a los 9 minutos de formular la pregunta, sin indicar al OP que [mejore su pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: las preguntas del tipo "hazmelo todo" no son bien recibidas, puedes mostrarnos que has intentado para poder ayudarte... @A.Cedano ahora si puedo ponerle negativo?

Comment: Entiendo que una pregunta debe de aportar lo investigado o lo que ha intentado OP, pero ¿Se les ocurre como hacer lo planteado en una sola consulta?

Comment: select Info_Pasajeros.Nombre from Tramo inner join Info_Pasajeros on Info_Pasajeros.NroVuelo=Tramo.NroVuelo inner join Avion_Utilizado on Avion_Utilizado.NroVuelo=Tramo.NroVuelo group by 
Info_Pasajeros.Nombre having count(Info_Pasajeros.CodPasajero)= count(Avion_Utilizado.CodAvion)

Comment: @RodrigoTorrico toda la información relevante debe ir en el contenido de tu pregunta. Los comentarios solo se usan para disipar dudas o discutir algunos detalles al respecto. Por esta ocasión se ha agregado la información de tu *query* a la pregunta, solo sería cuestión que lo consideres así para la próxima. Aún así, falta que agregues el motor de base de datos que estás utilizando actualmente.

Answer (score 1):

Primero necesitas unir las tablas `Info_pasajeros, Avion_Utilizado` mediante el item comun `nro-vuelo` un `join` también funcionaria.

luego usar la funcion `ALL` con un `subquery`, que seria la lista de todos los `nroavion`

```
SELECT nombre
  FROM Info_pasajeros, Avion_Utilizado
 WHERE Info_pasajeros.nro-vuelo=Avion_Utilizado.nro-vuelo and
nroavion = ALL 
       (SELECT UNIQUE(nroavion=
          FROM Avión_Utilizado)
```

referencias:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/all-subqueries.html
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp